# Filtering and moving tables from SQL Server to MS Access

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to selectively import data from SQL Server tables to MS Access tables.

As far as I understand, import full tables can be done quite easy with DoCmd commands.

Unfortunately, the data I need are stored in large tables and I only need a parcel of them.

So far, I was able to import the data and store them at a recordset.
Now I want to create a table to store at MS Access, but VBA is complaining of type mismatch (run-time error 3421).

So far my code is like that - first part: connection to SQL Server database and data acquisition

```
Sub Test()

Dim Table As String, SQL As String, SQLTable As String
Dim server As String, Database As String, GetClientDB As String

'CaseID = 0
'SolutionID = 498232069
Table = "PrSale"
SQL = PrSale(SolutionID, CaseId)
SQLTable = TableSQL(Table, SolutionID, CaseId)

server = ServerID
Database = DatabaseID
GetClientDB = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=" + Database + ";Data Source=" + server

Set DBConnection = New ADODB.Connection
DBConnection.CursorLocation = adUseServer

DBConnection.ConnectionString = GetClientDB
DBConnection.Open

Dim myview As ADODB.Recordset

'myview.Open SQLTable, DBConnection, adOpenStatic
Set myview = DBConnection.Execute(SQLTable)
```

Second part - table creation and fields definition:

```
Call DeleteIfExists(Table)

'Cria a tabela na base de dados
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
Set tdf = CurrentDb.CreateTableDef(Table)

'Lê os campos da tabela original e replica na tabela local
For Each viewfld In myview.Fields
    Dim fld As DAO.Field
    Dim mytype As Integer
    
    Select Case viewfld.Type
        Case 200   'VarChar
        mytype = dbText

        Case 3 'integer
        mytype = dbInteger

        Case 202 'VarWChar
        mytype = dbText

        Case 5 'Double
        mytype = dbDouble

        Case 2 'smallint
        mytype = dbInteger

        Case Else
        mytype = dbText
    End Select
    If Table = "PMPERIOD" Then
        If viewfld.Name = "StartDate" Or viewfld.Name = "StopDate" Then
            mytype = dbDate
        End If
    End If
    If Table = "PMSELL" Then
        If viewfld.Name = "GRPNUM" Then
        mytype = dbText
        End If
    End If
    Set fld = tdf.CreateField(viewfld.Name, mytype)
    tdf.Fields.Append fld
Next

CurrentDb.TableDefs.Append tdf
```

Third part - table fulfillment using data stored at myview recordset:

```
If myview.EOF Then
    GoTo Skip_
Else
End If

myview.MoveFirst

Do While Not myview.EOF
    'Preenche as tabelas com os dados do Recordset
    Dim myrecordset As DAO.Recordset
    Set myrecordset = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(Table)
    myrecordset.AddNew
    For Each viewfld In myview.Fields
        myrecordset.Fields(viewfld.Name).Value = viewfld.Value
        Dim j As Integer
        j = 10
    Next
    myrecordset.Update
    myview.MoveNext
Loop

Skip_:

End Sub
```

As far as I was able to debug, until the second part things seems to be right, although I was not able to verify the fields type. The table is created at the MS Access database with correct labels, but than it crashes with the error 3421! :(

How can I verify the type of the fields in tdf?

Do you have any clue what is going on?

Best regards

Comment: linked tables will solve most of your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Just setup a table link to the sql server table.

then fire up the Access query builder.

Now create a blank new query, drop in the linked table to sql server.

Now in the ribbon, change the query to a make table query.

You Have this:

[image]

So, you can pick the field  names, set critera, and when you run that query, it will create a local table.

So, you don't need code to filter

You don't need code to pick some columns

You don't need code to re-name the colum name(s) in the target table.

Just setup a linked table to sql server.

then drop in that linked table into the query builder.

On ribbon, choose "make table"

At this point, you can pick some, or all of the columns.

At this point you can type in criteria for some of the columns to limit the data.

run the query - you are done. There is no need to write code, or even mess with connection strings here.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this alternative.
This will also work if I use a parameter/form to define the filtering criteria?
The idea is to create an application to be used by others, not just by me, so I'm considering  creating a form so the user can select the SolutionID and CaseID in a "GUI".

Comment: Well, if they have to import live data all too often? Then you would be much better to have that setup work against SQL server, and not do all the hand stands to import data local - that does not seem wise. Unless there is a really good reason to pull data local, then you would setup access to filter and generate reports against the live database, and not pull data local - it is extra work, and often without benefits. But, yes, you can setup criteria against a form to do this, but then again, why not hit the live database then?

Comment: Indeed setup all this at server level would be better, but I'm not IT guy, so I don't have access to write this stuff at the server and to request that to the IT team would take a lot of time. I expect that the procedure will be executed at least once a month.
There will be more actions besides importing data. The data will be transformed and than consumed by other system I'd rather do this in a higher lever application, but, for now, it is MS Access or MS Excel. For this particular use, Access seems to be more adequate than Excel.

Comment: No problem. But give the above query idea a try. you can not only filter, but select which columns you want, and not want. And it takes no code. once pulled local, then of course you are free to do further updates, and slice and dice that local table.

Comment: I will, in fact I'm already using. Now I'll spend some time automating the filter criteria.
Nevertheless, I'm still trying to understand the issue with VBA approach. Maybe is a connection setup problem, because we have something similar in Excel and seems to work.

Comment: so far so good. I was able to create a form that use some parameters to filter another query.  I've also created queries to create tables "SELECT * INTO..."; How can run this query from a form without warnings? I was trying to use VBA but none of the methods that I've tried seems to work. DoCmd doesn't work with SELECT queries and Execute is also returning errors. :( Access "macros" also doesn't work.

Comment: You can use CurrentDb.Execute "my saved query or sql goes here" - it will not prompt. You might have to add dbseechanges, but try/use CurrentDb.Execute - it will not prompt the user for confirm of the sql action/query. So build the make table query that way in query builder, and then use CurrentDB.Execute to run it.

Comment: I ended up building Access "macros" that allows automation of tasks such as turning on and off the warnings. With your solution and macros I was able to do what I want. Thanks